# PHP mail function outlook UTF8

Tags: php, email, utf-8, outlook

My script:

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
  <style>td,tr{border:solid 1px black;}</style>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
  <tr><td>სახელი</td><td>{$_POST['firstname']}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>გვარი</td><td>{$_POST['lastname']}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>დაბადების თარიღი</td><td>{$_POST['birthday']}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>მოქალაქეობა</td><td>{$_POST['cityzen']}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>პირადი ნომერი</td><td>{$_POST['id_number']}</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
//MUSHA
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; utf-8' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <aaa.wwww@gmail.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I've tested it on gmail.com, yahoo.com, outlook.com and everything works great.

but in MS Outlook it has problem of UTF-8.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Thanks
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

I've wirtten like this and it works

Comment: @PiraTa Yup. You didn't notice, that I added the word: "charset="

Comment: I noticed, but you didn't notice, that I added the character: "-"
UTF-8
:D

Comment: @PiraTa Thank you. I updated the answer. The name of the encoding is really utf-8 :D.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
header("Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

to in top of your php file. Also Which version of Outlook you use?