# Character encoding in <form>

Tags: php, html, forms, utf-8

I´ve made a contact form, but since I´m not English I use characters such as "á","ň","š" etc.
But when I fill my form with those characters, I submit the form, and I recieve email, where all of these "unknown" characters are replaces with characters like "@-". The website is .html, not .php. I don´t store anything in the database.

I´ve put 
`<meta charset="UTF-8">` and also
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in the <head>`.
Also I modified `<form>` attribute to `<form id="contact-form" action="send_me" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">`
And I added `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` into my php file.
But nothing helped.

This is a piece of HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

.
.
.

```
<form id="contact-form" action="send_me" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="field-group">
    <div class="inputgroup">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" class="text form-input" type="name" name="name"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
    <div class="inputgroup">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" class="text form-input" type="message" name="message">
        </textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
    <div class="contact-form__button" style="">
        <input role="button" type="submit" name="submit">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="odo" class="contact-form__message"></div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".form-input").focus(function() {
    let parent = $(this).parent();
    if (!parent.hasClass("active")) {
        parent.addClass("active")
        }
 });
 $(".form-input").blur(function() {
    let self = $(this);
    let parent = self.parent();
    if (parent.hasClass("active") && self.val().length === 0) {
        parent.removeClass("active")
    }
 });
 $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = "sendMailB.php";
    messageHolder = $(".contact-form__message");
    messageHolder.removeClass();
    messageHolder.text('');
    const successMessage = 'Successfully sent!';
    const errorMessage = 'Oops, try later';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
                        messageHolder.addClass("success");            
                        messageHolder.text(successMessage);
        },
        error: function(error){
        console.log('error');
        messageHolder.addClass("error");
        messageHolder.text(errorMessage);
            }
    });
 });
```

PHP:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$to = "paula@soulmates.sk";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$extra = "From email: $email\r\n Answer to email: $email\r\n";<br>
$subject = "Mail from ".$name."";
$odkaz = $message;
$mess = "Name: ".$name."\nEmail: ".$email."\nPhone: ".$phone."\nMessage: ".$odkaz." \n";

$too = $email;
$subjectt = "Thank you for contacting us";
$messs = "Thank you message";
$extraa = "From email: $to\r\n Answer to email: $to\r\n";


mail ($to, $subject, $mess, $extra)
mail ($too, $subjectt, $messs, $extraa);

?>
```

I just need every infromation, that user puts into form to receive just the way they are. I need "Safaládka" to stay "Safaládka" in the received email, not to turn into for example "SafalˇA-dka"

Answer (score 1):

pass the header as fourth parameter in mail function.

```
mail ($to, $subject, $mess, $header);
```

Comment: I tried right now, nothing changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396373/php-mail-function-outlook-utf8 check this question